# how to emulate apache cookie flag for rewrites on apache 1.3

Tags: apache, mod-rewrite, cookies

I'm using Apache 1.3 with mod_rewrite it doesn't support the cookie|CO flag for rewrites. The code bellow works fine in Apache 2.0

```
# Works fine with Apache 2.0
RewriteRule ^/$ http://www.example.com/rs/ [CO=name:value:.example.com:240:/,R=301]
```

Is there a way to do the same with Apache 1.3?

Can I use:

```
Header set Set-Cookie "name=value; path=/; domain=.examplle.com"
```

to add the cookies only when a rewrite rule match?